# Dart : capture an image of a Flutter webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview, dart, flutter

I wonder if it's possible to capture an image of a webview?

Here is what I tried :

eg with **webview_flutter 0.1.0+1** :

```
   static GlobalKey previewContainer = new GlobalKey();
   ...            
                new RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: takeScreenShot,
                  child: const Text('Take a Screenshot'),
                ),
  ...
   takeScreenShot() async{
        RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = previewContainer.currentContext.findRenderObject();
        ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
        final directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
        ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
        Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
        File imgFile = new File(directory+'/screenshot.png');
        imgFile.writeAsBytes(pngBytes);

        //then, save the png image file in Firebase storage : OKAY
  }
```

First I tried to make a printscreen of a simple material button: **OKAY, it works**

```
    RepaintBoundary(
            key: previewContainer,
            child: 
                MaterialButton(
                     child: const Text('Test'),
                     textColor: Colors.white,
                    color: Colors.blue,

                ),
            ),
```

But when I try to make a printscreen of a webview, it doesn't work, the image saved is empty (just a few bytes) :

```
     RepaintBoundary(
            key: previewContainer,
            child: 
              new SizedBox(
                    height: 280.0,
                    width: 280.0,
                    child: WebView(
                      initialUrl: 'https://flutter.io',
                      javaScriptMode: JavaScriptMode.unrestricted,
                      onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController)                    {
                        _controller.complete(webViewController);
                      },
                    )
               ),
             )
```

Any idea?

or is there another way than *RepaintBoundary* to capture a png image?

Answer (score 0):

It happen to me that I had the same problem.

The short answer is that `RepaintBoundary` **cannot** capture WebView's content because it was displayed by native elements under the hood (i.e. `WKWebView` on iOS and `WebView` on Android)

So, the only solution I've found was to capture content directly from native element. Unfortunately, that's not a trivial task to do with `webview_flutter 0.1.0+1`, but there is another package that do the thing - `flutter_inappbrowser` https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappbrowser

Once you connected this library you can get the image this way:

```
_controller.takeScreenshot().then((bytes) async {
  var len = bytes.lengthInBytes;
  debugPrint("screenshot taken bytes $len");

  final directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
  String fileName = DateTime.now().toIso8601String();
  var path = '$directory/$fileName.png';

  File imgFile = new File(path);
  await imgFile.writeAsBytes(bytes).then((onValue) {
    ShareExtend.share(imgFile.path, "Screenshot taken");
  });
});
```

P.S. It works on iOS 11+ and on Android it uses deprecated method, so might be not supported in a time.

Comment: `flutter_inappbrowser`  is not saving the image in path that comes from `(await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path`. How can I know where is it saving the image??

Comment: the code is working perfect. I changed just one thing. Changed ` File imgFile = new File(path);` to `File imgFile = await File(path).writeAsBytes(value);`. Thanks @TramPamPam